# Testing my Load Balancer

Tags: ip, tcp, source

To test my Load Balancer I would need to create several TCP/IP connections (from one host).
Which tool can be used to create this sessions with different source-ip addresses?
(no worries, only in my private LAN).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to assign multiple IPs to a host, and then use something that lets you bind to specific source IPs. Since this is TCP/IP and you need to handle the response, crafting is probably just a pain.

With linux, you could use Curl for http connections if that is what you happen to be using:

```
   --interface <name>
          Perform  an operation using a specified interface. You can enter
          interface name, IP address or host name. An example  could  look
          like:

           curl --interface eth0:1 http://www.netscape.com/
```

Also with Linux, if you want lower level tcp, you might consider netcat `nc`.

Comment: Excuse me but, what does the `eth0:1` means? The curl man page does not explaint it.